# How JavaScript assigns `name` attribute of function?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, when I define function like this

`function aaa(){}`

I can later access the name by `name` attribute:

`aaa.name`

which will return

`"aaa"`

However, when I define function via `var`, it technically should be anonymous function without `name` attribute:

`var aaa=function(){}`

But instead it assumes that `aaa` is function name and assigns it to `name` attribute:

`aaa.name`

will also return

`"aaa"`

How JavaScript decides what should be the `name`, especially considering the fact that assignments could use more complicated scenarios:

`var aaa=bbb=function(){}`
or
`var aaa=arr[0]=function(){}`

?

Comment: It's an ES6 feature called [inferred function names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript declares the `name` variable of the function by taking the left-hand side argument that is equal to the function, which is `'aaa'` in all basic cases. In the first complex definition, you declared state above Javascript will take the variable `ab` and assign it to a function making the name `'ab'`. In the final example, you provided it sets the function equal to a pointer in memory, which is not a defined variable, this sets the `name` property to an empty string because `arr[0]` is not a variable name but a pointer to memory.
Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3ovuwfL/) displaying this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

> Inferred function names
>
> Variables and methods can infer the name of an anonymous function from
>   its syntactic position (new in ECMAScript 2015).
>
> ```
> var f = function() {}; 
> var object = {   
>     someMethod: function() {} 
> };
> console.log(f.name); // "f" 
> console.log(object.someMethod.name); // "someMethod"
> ```

Read the entire [blog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). It will clear all your queries.